# How to simulteniously delete elements from two Arraylists based one same index value in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have two arraylists which contains two set of strings.For example List domainList contain {'gmail','yahoo','yahoo','aol'}, and list flagList contains {'Y,'N','N','Y'} .So now since yahoo is twice in the list i have to remove one 'yahoo' from this  domainList and also its corresponding flag from flagList.The resuting list will be {'gmail','yahoo','aol'} and {'Y','N','Y'}.I am not sure how to do that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is regrettably cliche, but...what have you actually tried to solve this and where'd you get stuck?

Comment: I have only read legends about suggesting jQuery for problem solving. Was it a lie all along?

Comment: Also, even if that is certainly doable, it's a big design smell. You should have a single list of objects, where each object would contain a searchEngine field, and a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As folks have noted in the comments, you could explore creating a class to hold related information, and then use a single list of instances of this class.

However, if you really want to delete repeated elements from one list while keeping another in sync, you can use a `Set` to keep track of what's been seen already, and an `Iterator` to go through the list and remove elements that are already present in the set:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  List<String> domainList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("gmail","yahoo","yahoo","aol"));
  List<String> flagList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Y","N","N","N"));

  Set<String> seen = new HashSet<String>();
  Iterator<String> di = domainList.iterator();
  Iterator<String> fi = flagList.iterator();
  while(di.hasNext() && fi.hasNext())
  {
    fi.next(); // don't care about result
    String domain = di.next();
    if(!seen.add(domain)) 
    {
      di.remove();
      fi.remove();
    }
  }    
  System.out.println(domainList);
  System.out.println(flagList);
}
```

Output:

```
[gmail, yahoo, aol] 
[Y, N, N]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list contains strings you can use this approach:

```
    List<String> notUniqueList = Arrays.asList("gmail", "yahoo", "yahoo", "aol");
    List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(notUniqueList));
    for (String s : uniqueList) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

The print result:

```
gmail
yahoo
aol
```

If you are going use a custom object instead of String.class do not forget [override equals() and hashcode() methods](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3305792/learn-java/java-challengers-4-comparing-java-objects-with-equals-and-hashcode.html).